# Table is getting appended instead of creating a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm writing a webpage where there is a table created with data from database. And here I'm using Ajax.

And below is my code.
**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <marquee>
        <h1>This is an example of ajax</h1>
    </marquee>

    <p>
        Date: <input type="text" id="startDatePicker">
    </p>
    <p>
        Date: <input type="text" id="endDatePicker">
    </p>

    <form name="vinform">
        Enter id:<input type="button" id="vutton" value="Click Me">
    </form>
    <span id="tableDiv"> <span id="err">Select Correct Dates</span>
    </span>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="table.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**table.js**

```
var startDate = $("#startDatePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
});
var endDate = $("#endDatePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
});
$('#vutton').click(function() {
     $.getJSON('ControllerServlet', {
        'startDate' : startDate.val(),
        'endDate' : endDate.val()
    }, function(searchList) {
         var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($('#tabDiv'));
         $.each(searchList, function(index, result) {
         $('#err').hide();
         $('<tr>').appendTo($table).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.caseNumber)).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.caseOwner)).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.status)).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.issue)).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.reason)).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.age));
         });
    });
});
```

Here each time i click on the button the table data gets appended instead of displaying only current result. I think this is due to the `append` in my `javascript`, Here I want to know how can i display table only, on each click of button based on the parameters, i want a new table to be displayed instead of getting appended to the existing one.

Please tell me how can i do this.

Thanks

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: Hi @Quentin, do you want me to replace `var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($('#somediv'));` with `var $table = $('<table>').replaceWith($('#somediv'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this would help if you don't want the err span to be removed

```
var startDate = $("#startDatePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
});
var endDate = $("#endDatePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
});
$('#vutton').click(function() {
     $.getJSON('ControllerServlet', {
        'startDate' : startDate.val(),
        'endDate' : endDate.val()
    }, function(searchList) {
         $('#tabDiv > table').remove(); // here's the trick
         var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($('#tabDiv'));
         $.each(searchList, function(index, result) {
         $('#err').hide();
         $('<tr>').appendTo($table).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.caseNumber)).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.caseOwner)).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.status)).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.issue)).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.reason)).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.age));
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is still appending instead of replacing

Comment: @Rakesh this is the fiddle showing the flow with alert in between showing that the table is replaced https://jsfiddle.net/xda0xt56/

Comment: Thanks Man, this is what i was expecting

Comment: The copy and paste from my answer is really interesting :P

Comment: what makes you think that it is copy paste... the logic here is totally different. sorry if you think that way buddy... @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: Your improvement is fine, but the code is copied from my answer because the comment in the added line is exactly the same. I don't be envy, but is curious.

Comment: I w'll have to agree with that part... but the comment is just to show where the actual answer to the question lies in the code

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to remove all content before add the new table:

```
var startDate = $("#startDatePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
});
var endDate = $("#endDatePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
});
$('#vutton').click(function() {
     $.getJSON('ControllerServlet', {
        'startDate' : startDate.val(),
        'endDate' : endDate.val()
    }, function(searchList) {
         $('#tabDiv').html(""); //here's the trick
         var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($('#tabDiv'));
         $.each(searchList, function(index, result) {
         $('#err').hide();
         $('<tr>').appendTo($table).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.caseNumber)).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.caseOwner)).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.status)).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.issue)).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.reason)).append(
                $('<td>').text(result.age));
         });
    });
});
```

But with this information I can't help you more.

Comment: Can you please brief abit more

Comment: Yes, with the line `$(selector).html("")` you remove all content inside `selector` and then you append the table in the empty container. `selector === #tabDiv`

Comment: Hi, if you don't mind, can you please update my js file in your answer

Comment: Yes, here you are, but is only adding one line before the table appending